# Dropdown list items

Tags: html, css

I have two issues for my below code.

1. The alignment of my dropdown item's text line (excluding the first search line). As you can see I have two text in same line  - one is english and another one is arabic. I want to align the english text to left and arabic text to right with blank space in middle so both will not meet each other.
2. I want to add the double lined item for dropdown (each dropdown list item will have two lines). This second line is for english version only, also I want to keep single href link for whole line.

If anyone can help that will be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #61CE70;
  color: blue;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20pxpx;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.dropbtn {border-radius: 10px;}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(https://xyz.png); 
  float:input ;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #086815;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 298px;
  border-color: #086815;
  
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position:relative ;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #067B0A4A;
  min-width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #7A7A7A;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Sureh Al-Fatihah</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">1.Sureh Al-Fatihah          سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snippet here I add my code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #61CE70;
  color: blue;
  margin: 1px 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20pxpx;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.dropbtn {border-radius: 10px;}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url(https://xyz.png); 
  float:input ;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #086815;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 298px;
  border-color: #086815;
  
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position:relative ;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #067B0A4A;
  min-width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align-last: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  width: 300px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #7A7A7A;}

.show {display: block;}

/* ADD CSS */

div#myDropdown a span {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Sureh Al-Fatihah</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">1.Sureh Al-Fatihah <span>سُوْرَۃُ الفَاتِحَة</span> </a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hemant, would you please also review my second point?

Comment: Can anybody help here? waiting for reply.